# how do you get the length of a line in a text file?

Tags: python, text-files

```
line = initDict.readline()
  while line:
    line = initDict.readline()
    print(line)
    if len(line) == 5: # <<< problem
      line = initDict.readline()
      transfer.append(line)
```

I'm trying to get the length of the line, not the line number.

Input:

```
1
22
33335
4444
55555
```

Output:

```
55555 (line 5)
```

(where’s 33335? (line 3))

Comment: This _is_ the length.

Comment: `i’m trying to get the length of the line, not the line number` can you explain with example?

Comment: the programs getting the number on text line “5” but not the amount of characters on line “5”

Answer (score 1):

You *are* checking the length. That's not the problem.

The real problems are that, first, the lines you're reading include the line terminator character. Instead of `'33335'`, you're getting `'33335\n'`, which is 6 characters. Instead of `'4444'`, you're getting `'4444\n'`, which is 5 characters.

The second problem is that after you read a line and find it has 5 characters, you read *another* line and store *that* line instead of the one that actually had 5 characters. `'4444\n'` passes the check, but you append `'55555\n'` instead (or maybe it's `'55555'` if your file doesn't end with a line terminator).

You need to remove the trailing line break, and store the lines that match the check instead of the lines immediately after:

```
for line in initDict:
    line = line.removesuffix('\n')
    if len(line) == 5:
        transfer.append(line)
```

Comment: 1: .removesuffix isn’t a thing.                   2: use “.replace(“\n”,””)”

Comment: @clownfish: [`removesuffix` is in fact a thing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix), but if you're on a Python version below 3.9, you may not have access to it.